# Bash script traverse and compare file dates in loop

Tags: bash, file, date, loops, compare

So I want to compare the modified dates of files in a folder. I know you can compare that with -nt or -ot, but I don't know how to traverse through the files and compare them. I know you have to assign a file to be the previous one but I do not know the code for that.

For example, I have a folder with say 3 files, a, b and c. In the for loop, I want to compare a (previous entry) with b (entry). If a is newer than b, then delete b. And so on.

I'm trying to figure out how to assign "previous entry".

Thank you kindly!

```
echo "Which directory would you like to clean?"
read directory
echo "Are you sure you want to delete old back ups? Y for yes"
read decision
if [ $decision = "y" ]
then
for entry in "$directory"/*

do
#need to somehow assign the previous entry and current entry to a variable
if [ $entry -nt $previousEntry ]
rm -i $previousEntry
echo "Deleted $previousEntry"
fi
done
echo "Deleted all old files"

else
echo "Exiting"
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: what exactly is the ultimate goal? and how do you compare? `file1` vs `which file`?

Comment: what is previous entry?? if you tell us ultimately what you want to do, there might be other ways. If you want to delete files `older` than some given date, recursively, it can be done in one line. (`older` is a difficult word~~)

Comment: what you have mentioned, is it something like this? `for i in *; do if [ -n $j ]; then if [ $i -nt $j ]; then echo "$j newer than $i"; fi; fi; j=$i; done`? Suppose you have 3 files, a,b,c created in the mentioned order, so you will get `a newer than b; b newer than c;` as output.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm kind of looking for.

Comment: then ultimately you will be left with the latest created file, So for that why not use `ls -t|head -1`

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Do I add that in the `for` loop? Or...?

Comment: if your files are in same directory, just `cd $dir; ls -tr | head --lines=-1|xargs rm -f ; cd -` this will move to that dir, list all files in chronological order, reverse, so oldest file comes first, etc. Then `head --lines=-1` will keep all other files except the last one, i.e. latest file. Then xargs will execute the command for each of them

Comment: I'm receiving an error stating `OLDPWD not set` and the backups aren't in the same directory the code is being run. I would like it go to the directory that the user specifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. 2 nested `for` loops. Thank you me.

```
echo "Which directory would you like to clean?"
read directory
echo "Are you sure you want to delete old back ups? Y for yes"
read decision
if [ $decision = "y" ]
then

# Beginning of outer loop.
for entry in "$directory"/*
do
  # Beginning of inner loop.
  for previousEntry in "$directory"/*

  do
if [[ $entry -nt $previousEntry ]] #nt = newer than
then
echo "$entry is newer than $previousEntry"
echo "Deleting $previousEntry"
rm -i $previousEntry
fi 
  done
  # End of inner loop.

done

fi #end first if
```

Comment: great :) nice approach :), just put  `rm -i $previousEntry 2>/dev/null` to make it cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Here I am just moving to that directory and deleting all files except the latest one.

```
echo "Which directory would you like to clean?"
read directory
echo "Are you sure you want to delete old back ups? Y for yes"
read decision
if [ $decision = "y" ]
then
cd $directory
ls -tr | head --lines=-1|xargs rm -f  ;
echo "Deleted all old files"

else
echo "Exiting"
exit 1
fi
```